Change of priority in the table
I have priority column in the table priority_list as below.
Priority  Header
  1         A       
  2         B         
  3         C         
  4         D
  5         E

If I change priority with new priority number then other priorities should get rearranged
For example
If I change 4 to 3 then records will be as below
Priority  Header
  5         A
  1         B
  2         C
  3         D
  4         E

How can I achieve this..Pls Help!!!
I tried procedure where I have taken input parameters as I_priority, I_Case_Type
And updating the the priority as
Update priority_list 
  set priority= I_Priority - 1 
where priority<(select priority from priority_list where priority=I_Priority);

But not getting the desired result

you mean 4 to 5?

add a new column alter table yourTable add updated_date default sysdate; then use select.... order by updated_date desc

You can use a UPDATE statement and update all the rows between the old- and new-priorities.
For example, if you want to change from :old_priority := 1 to :new_priority := 5 then:
UPDATE table_name
SET priority = CASE
               WHEN priority > :old_priority THEN priority - 1
               WHEN priority < :old_priority THEN priority + 1
                                             ELSE :new_priority
               END
WHERE priority BETWEEN LEAST(:old_priority, :new_priority)
                   AND GREATEST(:old_priority, :new_priority);

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Priority, Header) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL      
SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'E' FROM DUAL;

Then, after the UPDATE, the table contains:



PRIORITY
HEADER




5
A


1
B


2
C


3
D


4
E



fiddle

If you need a general formula to change old to new, rotating the values in between, where old < new and both in the range of min:max priorities:
CASE
  WHEN :old_priority - :new_priority > 0
       THEN
       CASE               
          WHEN priority >= :new_priority AND priority < :old_priority
               THEN priority + 1
          WHEN priority = :old_priority 
               THEN :new_priority 
          ELSE priority
       END
 WHEN :old_priority - :new_priority < 0
      THEN
      CASE               
         WHEN priority = :old_priority 
              THEN :new_priority
         WHEN priority > :old_priority AND priority <= :new_priority
              THEN priority - 1
         ELSE priority
      END
ELSE priority
END

For (2,4) giving:



org_priority
new_priority
header




1
1
A


2
4
B


3
2
C


4
3
D


5
5
E



And for (2,3)
|org_priority|new_priority|header|
|------------|------------|------|
|1|1|A|
|2|3|B|
|3|2|C|
|4|4|D|
|5|5|E|
And for (1,5)
|org_priority|new_priority|header|
|------------|------------|------|
|1|5|A|
|2|1|B|
|3|2|C|
|4|3|D|
|5|4|E|
